# Can I use a custom UIImageView setter with SDWebImage?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, sdwebimage

When my image finishes downloading with SDWebImage, and it sets my table view cell's image view property, I want to be notified of this in the most transparent way possible.

My first idea was to use a custom setter for my image view, but as SDWebImage sets the .image propety of the image view, I don't have access to that setter to customize.

Right now I just use a didFinishDownloading custom delegate in the completion block of SDWebImage's downloader, but I'd rather it happen automatically. Is there any better way I can be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this function of `SDWebImage`:

```
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder completed:(SDWebImageCompletedBlock)completedBlock;
```

In `completedBlock` you can (for example) post some `NSNotification` 
Set observer with needed selector for corresponding notification and handle it.